# Node JS function undefined after execution

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to import simple class in node JS, I'm getting **undefined** after function execution. Why I'm getting the *undefined*?

**index.js**

```
const ctrl = require('./math');

console.log(ctrl.addFunction());
console.log(ctrl.sunFunction());
```

**math.js**

```
module.exports = {
  addFunction: function() {
    console.log('printing addFunction');
  },
  sunFunction: function() {
    console.log('printing sunFunction');
  }
};
```

**Output :**
node index.js
printing addFunction
 
undefined
 
printing sunFunction
 
undefined

Comment: The `undefined` is the return value of both functions and printed by your `index.js`.

Comment: Why two `console.log`? Just invoke function without `console.log` ie `ctrl.addFunction();`

Comment: if my functions doesn't  return any value then its undefined  got it. thanks @Sirko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to print whatever the functions return, and **they don't return anything**, they just print the strings from `console.log`.

The execution trace is:

```
console.log(ctrl.addFunction());
     > addFunction() 
             > prints 'printing addFunction' //First console.log in output
             > returns nothing
     > console.log(undefined) //Second console.log in output
```